# Polygonization of detected Contours

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to extract the relevant points of a given contour which I detected using some preprocessing and the [findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) function in opencv. Here is one example
[contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIaN3.png). The "peaks" in the lines should be smoothed out. Currently I use the Lang algorithm for doing this task.

```
def lang(tolerance,p,step):
    mask = np.ones(len(p),dtype='bool')
    start = 0
    end = 2

    marker = np.array([p[start],p[end]],dtype='double')

    if step == -1:
        maxstep = len(p)
    else:
    maxstep = min(step,len(p))

    while end < len(p) and end < maxstep:
        bGreater = False
        for i in range(start,end):
            ldist = point_line_distance(p[i,0],p[i,1],
                                    p[start,0],p[start,1],
                                    p[end,0],p[end,1])
            if ldist>tolerance:
                bGreater = True
                break
        marker = np.array([p[start],p[end]])
        if bGreater:
            mask[start+1:end-1] = False
            start = end-1
            end = start+2
        else:
            end = end+1
    mask[start+1:end-1]=False
 
    return mask,marker
```

[Lang Implementation](https://github.com/keszegrobert/polyline-simplification/blob/master/6.%20Lang.ipynb)

It functions quite well with some adjusting of the tolerance and step size. The major drawback is, that it also smooths out the chamfers at the corners and other points of the contours.

Does anyone have a better suggestion?
Here are the points of the example contour:

```
array([[[ 508, 1659]],
   [[ 507, 1660]],
   [[ 478, 1660]],
   [[ 473, 1665]],
   [[ 473, 1666]],
   [[ 472, 1667]],
   [[ 472, 1724]],
   [[ 471, 1725]],
   [[ 418, 1725]],
   [[ 417, 1724]],
   [[ 417, 1723]],
   [[ 418, 1722]],
   [[ 418, 1718]],
   [[ 419, 1717]],
   [[ 416, 1717]],
   [[ 417, 1718]],
   [[ 417, 1724]],
   [[ 416, 1725]],
   [[ 406, 1725]],
   [[ 471, 1725]],
   [[ 472, 1726]],
   [[ 472, 1772]],
   [[ 476, 1776]],
   [[ 476, 1778]],
   [[ 478, 1778]],
   [[ 479, 1779]],
   [[ 714, 1779]],
   [[ 715, 1780]],
   [[ 716, 1779]],
   [[1594, 1779]],
   [[1595, 1780]],
   [[1595, 2013]],
   [[1594, 2014]],
   [[1593, 2014]],
   [[1594, 2014]],
   [[1595, 2015]],
   [[1595, 2026]],
   [[1595, 1780]],
   [[1596, 1779]],
   [[1766, 1779]],
   [[1767, 1778]],
   [[1768, 1778]],
   [[1771, 1775]],
   [[1772, 1775]],
   [[1772, 1773]],
   [[1773, 1772]],
   [[1773, 1667]],
   [[1772, 1666]],
   [[1772, 1663]],
   [[1770, 1663]],
   [[1767, 1660]],
   [[1685, 1660]],
   [[1684, 1659]],
   [[1683, 1659]],
   [[1682, 1660]],
   [[1124, 1660]],
   [[1123, 1659]],
   [[1122, 1659]],
   [[1121, 1660]],
   [[ 563, 1660]],
   [[ 562, 1659]],
   [[ 561, 1659]],
   [[ 560, 1660]],
   [[ 510, 1660]],
   [[ 509, 1659]]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to draw the contour on an image(thickness = -1), do some processing on the image to remove the peak lines. After that find the new contour from the processed image(this will be without peaks).

I have stored your contour in a variable `cont`. The remaining code is shared.

```py
img = np.zeros((2500, 2500, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(img, [cont], -1, 255, -1)

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=2)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=2)

Contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]
Contour = sorted(Contours, key=lambda x:cv2.contourArea(x))[0]
```

Your resultant contour without peaks is stored in the variable `Contour`.

Below is the image with the initial contour drawn with thickness = -1 flag.
[image: initial]

Below is the image after processing.
[image: after processing]

Below is the image with the final contour drawn without peaks.
[image: final]

Answer (score 0):

Consider a different simplifier.  Visvalingamwyatt minimizes area change, and worked well for me with your sample set.  There's in implementation in pypi:
https://pypi.org/project/visvalingamwyatt/ or just `pip install visvalingamwyatt`

For your vector, I did: `vv.simplify(b, threshold=8)`.  It eliminated the spikes, and although the chamfers are simplified, the corners are still accurate.